# Flexslider in easyTabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, flexslider

I have a Flexslider Gallery in an [jQueryEasyTabs](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/) Tab but my gallery images will don't show when I click on the 'gallery' tab. 
I think there is a `'easytabs:after'` callback but it don't work. How can I fix that?

```
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#sub-special">Special Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#sub-gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content" id="sub-gallery">
                    <div class="flexslider">
                      <ul class="slides">
                        <li data-thumb="./images/gallery/1.jpg">
                          <img src="./images/gallery/1.jpg" />
                        </li>
                        <li data-thumb="./images/gallery/2.jpg">
                          <img src="./images/gallery/2.jpg" />
                        </li>
                        <li data-thumb="./images/gallery/3.jpg">
                          <img src="./images/gallery/3.jpg" />
                        </li>
                        <li data-thumb="./images/gallery/4.jpg">
                          <img src="./images/gallery/4.jpg" />
                        </li>
                        <li data-thumb="./images/gallery/5.jpg">
                          <img src="./images/gallery/5.jpg" />
                        </li>
                        <li data-thumb="./images/gallery/6.jpg">
                          <img src="./images/gallery/6.jpg" />
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>


/* Flexslider Gallery */
$('#sub-gallery .flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: 'slide',
    smoothHeight: true,
    slideshow: false
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this helped me:

```
$('#tab-container').easytabs({
    defaultTab: "#defaultTab"
}).bind('easytabs:after', function(){
    console.log('after fired up!')
    $('#sub-gallery .flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        smoothHeight: true,
        slideshow: false
    }); 
});
```